# $\int_0^{+\infty}{ \sin{(ax)} \sin{(bx)}}dx=?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How can I calculate the integral:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}{ \sin{(ax)} \sin{(bx)}}dx$$ ??

I got stuck.. :/

Could you give me some hint??

Do I have to use the following formula??

$\displaystyle{\sin{(A)} \sin{(B)}=\frac{\cos{(A-B)}-\cos{(A+B)}}{2}}$

Comment: Yes, you can use this formula and it will work, just integrate each term separately.

Comment: Yes, and use the fact that: $\int\cos(mx)\,\mathrm dx=\tfrac{\sin(mx)}{m}+\text{const.}$

Comment: Using this formula I would have the following:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}{ \sin{(ax)} \sin{(bx)}}dx=\int_0^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos{((a-b)x)} -\cos{((a+b)x)} }{2}}dx=\int_0^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos{((a-b)x)}}}{2}dx -\int_0^{+\infty}{\cos{((a+b)x)} }{2}}dx=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{a-b} \sin{((a-b)x)}]_0^{+\infty}-\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{a+b} \sin{((a+b)x)}]_0^{+\infty}$$ But can we calculate the limit of $\displaystyle{\sin{((a-b)x)}}$ and $\displaystyle{\sin{((a+b)x)}}$ when $\displaystyle{x \rightarrow +\infty}$??

Comment: This is exactly where stands the problem (I bet).

Comment: Using this formula I would have the following: 
$$\int_0^{+\infty}{ \sin{(ax)} \sin{(bx)}}dx=\int_0^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos{((a-b)x)} -\cos{((a+b)x)} }{2}}dx=\int_0^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos{((a-b)x)}}}{2}dx -\int_0^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos{((a+b)x)} }{2}}dx=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{a-b} \sin{((a-b)x)}]_0^{+\infty}-\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{a+b} \sin{((a+b)x)}]_0^{+\infty}$$
 But can we calculate the limit of $sin((a−b)x)$  and $sin((a+b)x)$  when $x→+∞$ ??

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici So can I not find the value of the integral???

Comment: Or maybe the integral simply does not exist.

Comment: This integral will not converge as the function oscillates forever without any damping.

Comment: As said it comments, the integral does not converge. This was the problem. Cheers :)

Comment: This integral does not converge in the usual sense. It does converge in *distribution* but that opens up a very deep can of worms.

Comment: May I ask in what context the integral appeared?

Comment: @Thorben At the calculation of the coeffiecients of the heat equation with $x>0$ and $t>0$.

Comment: @MaryStar Ah ok, I was solving some integral I found on MSte. today and I ended up with exactly the same question as you posed above (even the same parameters $a$ and $b$). Thus I thought you are maybe working on the same :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral does not converge but one can make some sense of it anyway as a generalized function of $a$ and $b$. Specifically, the result is a sum of Dirac delta functions. To show this, use the Euler identity to express the sine functions as exponential functions. After a little simplification, you will have several terms and each can be evaluated using the Dirac delta function's Fourier expansion:
\begin{equation}
\delta(p) = {1\over2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx e^{i p x}
\end{equation}

Edit: To be clear, this is a somewhat advanced analysis. If this was a homework problem for an elementary class and you've never heard of any of the techniques or formulas I've mentioned, the sought-after answer is probably simply "integral does not exist" which can be demonstrated via the arguments made by other posters.

Comment: I will try to do it in the way you mentioned..
From the Euler identity $e^{i \phi}=\cos{\phi} +i \sin{\phi}$, we get:
$$e^{i ax}=\cos{ax} +i \sin{ax} \Rightarrow \sin{ax}=-i e^{i ax}+i \cos{ax}$$
$$e^{i bx}=\cos{bx} +i \sin{bx} \Rightarrow \sin{bx}=-i e^{i bx}+i \cos{bx}$$
$$\sin{(ax)} \sin{(bx)}=(-i e^{i ax}+i \cos{(ax)})(-i e^{i bx}+i \cos{(bx)})=-e^{i(a+b)x}+e^{i ax} \cos{(bx)}+e^{i bx} \cos{(ax)}-\cos{(ax)} \cos{(bx)}$$
How can I continue??

Comment: You can completely replace the sines with exponentials, no need for cosines. The conjugate of the Euler equation is an independent algebraic equation for these purposes. So you have two equations $e^{\pm i \phi} = \cos\phi \pm i \sin\phi$, i.e. with both the plus and the minus. You can solve those two equations to get $2i \sin\phi = e^{i\phi} -e^{-i\phi}$. Using this last equation, you can write the integrand just as a sum of exponentials and then use the Dirac delta function formula on each term to get the final result.

Comment: Ahaa.. So is it as followed?
$$\sin{(ax)}=-i \frac{e^{i ax}-e^{-i ax}}{2}$$
$$\sin{(bx)}=-i \frac{e^{i bx}-e^{-i bx}}{2}$$
$$\sin{(ax)} \sin{(bx)}=(-i \frac{e^{i ax}-e^{-i ax}}{2})(-i \frac{e^{i bx}-e^{-i bx}}{2})=\frac{1}{4} (e^{i(a+b)x}-e^{i(a-b)x}-e^{-i(a-b)x)}+e^{-i(a+b)x})$$

Comment: Therefore,$$ \int_0^{+\infty}{\sin{(ax)} \sin{(bx)}}=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{+\infty}{e^{i(a+b)x}-e^{i(a-b)x}-e^{-i(a-b)x)}+e^{-i(a+b)x}}dx=\frac{1}{4}( \int_0^{+\infty}{e^{i(a+b)x}}dx-\int_0^{+\infty}{e^{i(a-b)x}}dx-\int_0^{+\infty}{e^{-i(a-b)x)}}dx+\int_0^{+\infty}{e^{-i(a+b)x}}dx)$$
We know that:
$$2 \pi \delta(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{ikx}}dk$$
Does it stand that:$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{ikx}}dk=2\int_0^{+\infty}{e^{ikx}}dk$$??

Comment: No, your last equation is false. Look at the four integrals you have. With a change of variables, you can combine the first and the last into a single integral over $(-\infty, \infty)$. You can combine the second and third similarly.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right!!! So, it is as followed:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}{ \sin{(ax)} \sin{(bx)}}dx=\frac{1}{4}(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{i(a+b)x}}dx-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{i(a-b)x}}dx)=\frac{1}{4}(2 \pi \delta(a+b)-2 \pi \delta(a-b))=\frac{\pi}{2}(\delta(a+b)-\delta(a-b))$$
Is this correct??

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. But I would double check all the constants and signs since I did not do out the calculation in full myself. And please accept my answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Ok!!! Thank you for your helpful answer!!! :-)

Comment: A tough mix of right and wrong. The sign is wrong IMHO. If one uses the sloppy interpretation of $\delta(0) = +\infty$, we would need get $+\infty$ for $a=b$ and $-\infty$ for $a = -b$.

Comment: In my notes I have:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}{sin{(k'x)}f(x)}dx=\int_0^{+\infty}{sin{(k'x)} \sin{(kx)}dx A(k)}dk $$
From the relation $$\int_0^{+\infty}{\sin{(kx)} \sin{(k'x)}}dx=\frac{\pi}{2} \delta(k-k')$$ we have that:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}{sin{(k'x)}f(x)}dx=\int_0^{+\infty}{\frac{\pi}{2} \delta(k-k') A(k)}dk=\frac{\pi}{2}A(k')$$
But I have found the following:$$\int_0^{+\infty}{\sin{(kx)} \sin{(k'x)}}dx=\frac{-\pi}{2} (\delta(k'+k)-\delta(k-k'))$$, so
$$\int_0^{+\infty}{sin{(k'x)}f(x)}dx=- \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{+\infty}{( \delta(k'+k)-\delta(k'-k)) A(k)}dk$$
Which of the results is the correct one??

Comment: In the given problem, $p\ne0$ and you trivially have $\delta(p)=0$. I wonder how this "convergence to zero" is justified in the theory of distributions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn't see any indication in the original problem that $a\ne \pm b$. At any rate, to prove the convergence to 0, I think you could do a contour integral along the real number line, closing in the upper half-plane for $p>0$ or lower half-plane for $p<0$. There are no poles so the entire integral vanishes. Furthermore, the closing arc in the upper (lower) half-plane is exponentially suppressed so it vanishes as well. Thus the integral over the real line must also vanish.

Comment: The case $a=\pm b$ does not worry me, it's obviously diverging. Your explanation is by the theory of complex variables, not distributions. I cannot make the link with real calculus, which clearly states that the integral does not converge. The integral in the sense of the Cauchy principal value does not apply here.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think it is consistent for the complex analysis argument to be correct within the sphere of its logical framework, while simultaneously the integral is simply undefined in the framework of real analysis. I'm a physicist by the way, so maybe I'm just missing your point since we tend to look at these things differently from how a mathematician would.

Comment: I have seen at different places that the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ is undefined, whereas that from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ can be seen as $0$ by odd parity (in the Cauchy sense). Indeed, the first form cannot stand a phase shift, while the second can.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\pars{ax}\sin\pars{bx}
\,\dd x}
={1 \over 4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\braces{%
\cos\pars{\bracks{a - b}x} -\cos\pars{\bracks{a + b}x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over 2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\expo{\ic\pars{a - b}x} -\expo{\ic\pars{a + b}x}}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi}
=\color{#66f}{\large%
{\pi \over 2}\bracks{\delta\pars{a - b} - \delta\pars{a + b}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b\neq0$, then the set $A:=\{x\in [0,2\pi/b]: |\sin(ax)|>1/2\}$ is non-empty (otherwise exchange $a,b$). $A$ is open, hence there exists $\epsilon>0$ so that $B:=\{x\in A: |\sin(bx)|>\epsilon\}$ is non empty. Since $B$ is open it has positive Lebesgue measure. It follows that

$$\int_0^\infty |\sin(ax)\sin(bx)|=\infty$$ and the integral doesnt exist. (Similar ways show that both the positive and negative parts are infinite as well.)

Answer (score 1):

This integral will not converge as the function oscillates forever without any damping and the primitive has no limit.

Comment: What if $a=b=0$? Then the integral will converge.

Comment: It also converges for $a=0, b\ne0$ or $a\ne0, b=0$, but that will not revolutionize integral calculus, I am afraid.

Comment: lol, that was a nice joke. ^^

Answer (score 1):

For the nontrivial cases $a \ne 0$, $b \ne 0$ the integrand
$$
f(x) = \sin(ax)\sin(bx)
$$
is oscilating somewhere between $1$ and $-1$ and that means the net area $I$ below the integral oscilates too and won't converge towards a finite value for the upper bound going towards $\infty$.
$$
I = 
\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int\limits_0^\beta \sin(ax)\sin(bx) \, dx 
\in \left\{ \mbox{undefined}, \pm \infty \right\}
$$
The infinite cases happen for $a=b$, because then $f(x)=\sin^2(ax) \ge 0$ and for $a=-b$ because then $f(x) =-\sin^2(ax) \le 0$.

Example plot:
[image]

Too lazy to do the integration myself, I asked Wolfram's Google killer for an answer and got
$$
\int \sin(ax)\sin(bx) \, dx =
\frac{b\sin(ax)\cos(bx)-a\cos(ax)\sin(bx)}{a^2 - b^2}
+ \mbox{const} \implies \\
I = \lim_{x->\infty} 
\frac{b\sin(ax)\cos(bx)-a\cos(ax)\sin(bx)}{a^2 - b^2}
$$

which asures me somewhat that I hit all three cases.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the integrand only periodic if $a$ and $b$ are commensurate? The logic here is that the period of the product must contain an integer number of both the periods corresponding to $a$ and $b$. This is impossible unless $a/b$ is rational. *Editted*

Comment: You could be right, let me think. The bit I meant was varying, it is not important that the same value is hit.